# Laravel show page only to signed in user

Tags: laravel

How do I show a page only to a specific person that's signed in. For example if I've localhost/public/article/4 that's only allowed for James, how do I make sure that Harry can't see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct way of do this is associate all users to a *Role* model. This way you could differenciate one user from others. But if you dont want this way you could use the ID of the user to validate this.

How validate this?

when you make a session in laravel you can access to the user data using

```
Auth::user()->id, Auth::user()->name, Auth::user()->last_login, etc...
```

in the controller's function the make the view you could do this (James ID's = 1)

```
if(Auth::user()->id == 1):
   return View::make('path_to_view.show');
else:
   return View::make('path_to_view.error');
endif;
```

Comment: Oke, thanks but already had the second part but do you have a site or article where the Role is explained?

Comment: the Role is basically a table, that contains the user types of your system, like Administrator, Operator, or "SimpleMortalUser" :) etc.... and in the users table you put an role_id field to foreign the roles table... It is based on the security of wordpress... https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities